# Is there a simple way of having a python list containing a given type of object only

Tags: python, list

Python lists allow different types of object to be present inside it. I want a python list to have a only a given type of object so that if someone do something like `mylist.append(differentobject)` or `mylist.insert(differentobject, index)`, an error is thrown. This is a trivial thing to do in java or c++ because we define the datatypes of our object while initializing them. I am wondering if there is a simple way of doing that in python (other than making our own custom class inheritting `MutableSequence` or `list` themselves). In more clear words, what I want is something like `mylist = list(MyObjectType)`.

Comment: With the python3 `typing` module: `mylist: typing.List[MyObjectType] = []`

Comment: Most Java lists don't actually enforce element types. (Java generics are only enforced by the compiler, and only if you don't use raw types.)

Comment: You can't change the behavior of built-in objects in `python` unless you create your own

Comment: @hnefatl it won't serve the purpose. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really (without subclassing `list`). You can use a generics with a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
from typing import List
mylist: List[MyObjectType] = []
```

But it has no effect when the script runs. To get it to raise an error, you would need to use [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) to run type checking over it. Last I checked, `mypy` worked fairly well but don't expect it to be as thorough as Java's type system.

Another option if it suits your purpose is to use Numpy arrays, which are typed:

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int)
myarray[0] = 4.3
assert myarray[0] == 4
myarray[1] = "foo"
# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'object'
```

But it only works for [various numerical primitives](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) and "objects" - so it wouldn't distinguish between different classes of object. And if it can, it will automatically cast between the different numerical types rather than raise an error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it was really helpful. But it looks like there is no way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exception to be thrown, you can use `isinstance()` and `assert`. Say, you wanted to add only integers:

```
assert isinstance(foo, int)

_list.append(foo)
```

If the value of `foo` is not an integer, an `AssertionError` will be thrown:

```
assert isinstance(foo, int)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-e38d44ae79ea>", line 1, in <module>
    assert isinstance(foo, int)

AssertionError
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, it's better to use `if` and raise a `ValueError` or some other more semantically accurate exception. The `assert` statement is not always run, depending on how Python is executed.